# Transactions in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, database

I have been asked an interesting question on implementing transactions in a stored procedure. And I don't have any idea on this.  Suppose I have 10 statements in a stored procedure. I would like at least 5 to commit always even the rest of other fail and I have to do this within a single transaction. Any idea how to implement this?. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this : SAVE TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx this will help you in how to achieve functionality